# When we should use new() keyword when inherited from generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I read an training article about generic class, it has some code like this :

```
public class ValidationBase {
  public virtual bool IsValidName(string name) {
    return name.Length > 5;
  }
}

 public class LogicBase<T> where T : ValidationBase, new() {
    private T _Validations = default(T);
      public T Validations {
        get {
          if (_Validations == null) {
            _Validations = new T();
           }
        return _Validations;
          }
       set { _Validations = value; }
      }
}
```

it said that :

> The new keyword creates an instance of the DataModelBase class by default if no specific type has been provided for T

I really don't understand when we should use `new()` keyword?

NOTE: if edit above code like this:

```
 public class LogicBase<T> where T : ValidationBase
```

instead of

```
 public class LogicBase<T> where T : ValidationBase, new()
```

what will happen?

Comment: You need the `new` generic constraint whenever you have to do use the constructor like `new T()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When specifying a generic class, `new()` acts as a constraint against the type that `T` can be.

In this case, `new()` is stating that the type of `T` must be a class with a public, parameterless constructor.

For instance:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T : new()
{
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public MyClass2(int i)
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // OK!
        MyGenericClass<MyClass> c1 = new MyGenericClass<MyClass>();

        // Gives the error:
        // 'MyClass2' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
        // constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type
        // or method 'MyGenericClass<T>'
        MyGenericClass<MyClass2> c2 = new MyGenericClass<MyClass2>();
    }
}
```

This is so that you can create a new instance of type `T` using `new T()`. As this is generic, all types of `T` must conform to the same rules. `where T: new()` forces all types of `T` to have a public, parameterless constructor.

You code:

```
if (_Validations == null) {
    _Validations = new T();
}
```

creates a new instance of `T`. As `T` could be anything, all types of `T` must therefore be able to be created using `new MyType()`.

Answer (score 2):

`New T()` is used to create a new instance of T using the constructor that has no parameters. This is possible only when you use the `new()` contraint in the generic definition.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of LogicBase states that the T would be of type ValidationBase and LogicBase will create a new instances of the type ValidationBase. new() is a constraint here.

Basically you are putting a constraint that says ValidationBase type should have a public parameterless constructor.

An example of how this matters would be, lets say ValidationBase was an abstract class and you pass it to LogicBase as the type argument, in which case LogicBase will give a compile error because you cannot create instances of abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

In the following snippet, you are trying to obtain an instance of the arbitrary class `T`:

```
if (_Validations == null) {
    _Validations = new T();
}
```

But since `T` is a generic type parameter, and can be anything at all, there is really no guarantee that an instance of `T` *can* be newed up like this. In order for this to compile, you must guarantee to the compiler that any type argument you provide for `LogicBase<T>` *does* indeed have a constructor with no arguments.

You guarantee this using the `new` type constraint in your class definition. This will make sure that anywhere you reify `T`, (eg. when instantiating or deriving from `LogicBase<FooBar>`), the type argument provided for `T` (in the previous examples, `FooBar`) has an empty constructor. If no matching constructor is available, you will get a compiler error.